# SQL Server : get values in table that only have certain keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Difficult question to ask and even search for. Here's my dilemma. I need to get IDs in a table that only have instances of certain keys in a column.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(myID1) as mainID 
FROM table1 
WHERE myID2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This works, however, I don't want to return any myID1 values (in table1) that have myID2 values (in table1) other than 1,2,3,4,5.

So, here's the example table....

```
id | myID1 | myID2
---+-------+------
1  |  234  | 2
2  |  234  | 3
3  |  235  | 2
4  |  235  | 6
```

In this instance, I only want to return the value **234**. 235 has a myID2 value of **6** in the table.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (id INT, myID1 INT, myID2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES
(1 , 234 , 2 ),
(2 , 234 , 3 ),
(3 , 235 , 2 ),
(4 , 235 , 6 )

SELECT DISTINCT myID1 as mainID 
FROM @Temp T
WHERE 
 T.myID2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @Temp T1 WHERE T1.myID2 NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND T.myID1 = T1.myID1)
```

Result:

```
mainID
-----------
234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(myID1) as mainID FROM table1 
WHERE myID2 IN (1,2,3,4,5) and myID1 not in (SELECT DISTINCT(myID1) as mainID FROM table1 
WHERE myID2 NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCEPT`. The general pseudocode is in values `EXCEPT` where not in values.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (id int, myID1 int, myID2 int)

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES (1, 234, 2), (2, 234, 3), (3, 235, 2), (4, 235, 6)

SELECT DISTINCT(myID1) as mainID 
FROM @table1 
WHERE myID2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT(myID1) as mainID 
FROM @table1 
WHERE myID2 NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Gives output:

```
mainID
234
```